# Using Fileinput to upload files

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to develop an app with a dashboard design to display the summary of the table and display the data frame.

I am quite unsuccessful, in designing it. I have incorporated my own dashboard design for this.

I am missing an element in my server function and not able to see the dataframe of the uplaoded file.

Any lead would be helful.

Below is my code for the UI and Server function

UI

```
  ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Model"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    id = "tabs",
    menuItem(
      "Data",
      tabName = "data",
      icon = icon("table"),
      startExpanded = TRUE,
      menuSubItem("Load", tabName = "data1")

    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tags$style(
        type = "text/css",
        ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
        ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
      ),
      tabItems(tabItem(
        tabName = "data1",
        fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
            fileInput(
              "file",
              "Choose CSV File",
              accept = c("text/csv",
                         "text/comma-seperated-values, text/plain",
                         ".csv")
            ),
            tags$hr(),
            checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
            radioButtons(
              "sep",
              "Separator",
              choices = c(
                Comma = ",",
                semicolon = ";",
                Tab = "\t"
              ),
              selected = ";"
            )
          ),
          mainPanel(uiOutput("tb"))
        )
      ))
    )
  )
```

SERVER CODE

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){
 data <- reactive({
   file1 <- input$file
   if(is.null(file1)){return()}
   read.csv(file = file$datapath, sep=input$sep)
 })
 output$filedf <- renderTable({
   if(is.null(data())){return()}
   input$file
 })
 output$sum <- renderTable({
   if(is.null(data())){return()}
   summary(data())
 })
 output$table <- renderTable({
   if(is.null(data())){return()}
   data()
 })
 output$tb <- renderUI({
   if(is.null(data())){return()}
   tabPanel("About file", tableOutput("filedf")),tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("Summary", tableOutput("sum"))

 })
  })
```

Comment: I know, that I making a mistake with Output$tb <- renderUI ; or missing some element in UI.. Could any one help to figure it out.

Comment: Just a trival thing here. You do not need to check `if(is.null(data())){return()}` at every step. As you have checked for null in the reactive function. A simple alternative to that is to use `req(input$file)`, in this way null are taken care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out there was a small typo in your code. You were referring to `input$file` and `file$datapath`, where that should have been `input$file1` and `file1$datapath`. So a working version would be as shown below. Hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui<-dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Model"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                menuItem("Data", tabName = "data", icon = icon("table"),startExpanded = TRUE,
                         menuSubItem("Load", tabName = "data1")

                ),
                menuItem("Visualisation",icon=icon("bar-chart-o"), tabName = "vis"),
                menuItem("Result", icon=icon("cog"), tabName = "result")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$style(type="text/css",
               ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
               ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
    ),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "data1",
              fluidPage(
                fluidRow(
                  fileInput("file1","Choose CSV File",
                            accept = c("text/csv",
                                       "text/comma-seperated-values, text/plain",
                                       ".csv")
                  ),
                  tags$hr(),
                  checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                  radioButtons("sep","Separator",
                               choices=c(Comma=",",
                                         semicolon=";",
                                         Tab="\t"),
                               selected = ";")
                ),
                mainPanel(
                  uiOutput("tb")
                )
              )
      )
    )
  )
) 


server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){
  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file1
    if(is.null(file1)){return()}
    read.csv(file = file1$datapath, sep=input$sep)
  })
  output$filedf <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return()}
    input$file1
  })
  output$sum <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return()}
    summary(data())
  })
  output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return()}
    data()
  })
  output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(data())){return()}
    tabsetPanel(tabPanel("About file", tableOutput("filedf")),tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("Summary", tableOutput("sum")))

  })
})



shinyApp(ui,server)
```